# how to prevent rsyslog from requiring /dev/xconsole?

Tags: rsyslog

My OS:

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
```

I am running it from inside a Singularity container. So, preferably no write access to `/dev/`:

```
service rsyslog start
 * Starting enhanced syslogd rsyslogd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
mknod: /dev/xconsole: Permission denied
chown: cannot access '/dev/xconsole': No such file or directory
```

How do I disable requesting of `/dev/xconsole`?
I uncommented the following lines in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf but it did not help:

```
daemon,mail.*;\
        news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
        *.=debug;*.=info;\
        *.=notice;*.=warn       /dev/tty8
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after looking at the package's source cod, I found out that commenting out the call to `create_xconsole` function in `/etc/init.d/rsyslog` did the trick:

```
case "$1" in
  start)
        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$RSYSLOGD"
        # create_xconsole
        do_start
```